# woocommerce: get the permalink of the product in quotelist plugin

Tags: wordpress, url, woocommerce, permalinks, contact-form-7

I'm using request a quote plugin and Contact form 7 in woocommerce,
I made a form with CF7 with some fields (Name, Surname, Address, etc.) 
but I'd also like to add in the form the link of the product,
I tried to add this in functions.php:

```
function cf7_add_url() {

$url = get_permalink( $product_id );

return $url;

}

add_shortcode('CF7_ADD_URL', 'cf7_add_url');
```

and this field in the CF module:

```
[dynamictext Url "CF7_ADD_URL"]
```

But what returns in the quotelist page is not the link of the product selected but the link of quotelist.

Which code I should put on there to see the permalink of the product for quote?
Thank you for any advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved putting:

```
[quotelist]
```

in the CF module mail tab